# Proving that $E[X|G] = E(X)$ when $G = \{\emptyset, \Omega\}$

Tags: probability-theory

Let $G = \{\emptyset, \Omega\}$ be the trivial $\sigma$-algebra. I know that $E(X|G) = E(X)$, but how do I prove that? From what I understood about conditional expectation, I have to prove that

$$\int_A E(X) dP = \int_A X dP$$

for every $A \in G$. Since $G$ contains only two elements, I just tried plugging them in. Obviously, if $A = \Omega$, then the right-hand side is exactly the definition of $E(X)$. But then, I'd have to prove that

$$\int_\Omega E(X) dP = E(X).$$

Since $E(X)$ is a constant, we can rewrite the left-hand side to

$$E(X)\int_\Omega 1 dP.$$

But then it must be true that

$$\int_\Omega 1 dP = 1.$$

Is that the case though?

On the other hand, if $A = \emptyset$, both integrals should equal $0$, so the equality holds.

Comment: The only functions that are measurable with respect to $G$ are the constants.

Comment: So what does this tell me?

Comment: Everything. ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 2):

$Y$ is a version of $E[X|G]$ **iff** $Y$ is $G$ measurable and $\int_A Y = \int_A X $ for
all $A \in G$.

The only functions that are measurable with respect to $G$ are the constants, so
$Y$ must be and must satisfy $\int_\Omega Y = Y\int_\Omega 1 = \int_\Omega X = EX$.

Comment: I don't get it. Is my own approach wrong then?

Comment: Not wrong, but the essential limiting feature is that $Y$ is $G$ measurable which you did not mention...